# VB.net Winforms dropdownbox data load question

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a VB2005 winforms application that will loads city data from my database table. This is to ensure that the user enters the correct city spelling, in order to receive an accurate quote. Currently, there are about 150K cities that are being loaded to the dropdown listbox on page load. It takes about 30-40 seconds for that page to load.

My initial thought was to allow the user to select the state first. Then load the city values. But the user has the option of going back and requesting a quote for a different city / state.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: I hope you are creating the data structures at application load and caching them rather than re-querying several times.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are based on state and city name?  If so, your approach sounds good, but consider basing quotes on zip instead, or zip/city name.  Not everyone will find their city in your 150K list, and some don't live in named cities at all.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you could have a BackgroundWorker or Thread load the data in the background into an array or list. You'd then pass this data to the comboBox when needed.

If you use this method, you must find a way of reindexing the fields from time to time though.